# Why no parentheses on this cursor declaration?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, syntax-error, cursors

I have a cursor declaration here:

```
declare c cursor
for     (select ProductName, ListPrice
        from Products
        where ListPrice > 700)
```

But if I add an `order by` clause, I get an error:

```
declare c cursor
for     (select ProductName, ListPrice
        from Products
        where ListPrice > 700
        order by ListPrice desc)
```

The error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.`

But the error goes away if I take away the parentheses:

```
declare c cursor
for     select ProductName, ListPrice
        from Products
        where ListPrice > 700
        order by ListPrice desc
```

Perhaps I'm a bit unclear about what the parentheses do in SQL Server.  What gives?  Why would the `order by` clause interact with the parentheses in that way?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't like `order by` in subqueries (unless you also have `top`).  I guess it interprets the query inside parentheses as a subquery, because the parens are not needed.

Comment: That makes sense.  You should put that in an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order by` is not allowed in subqueries, as noted in the comments.  Wrapping the `select` in parentheses makes SQL interpret it as a subquery.